# hash-based asyncronous directory comparison

Tags: git, rsync

I am trying to efficiently synchronize two large directories via VPN over a long distance. Unfortunately I cannot install advanced tools like git or rsync on the remote server due to company restrictions.

I am thus looking for an alternative solution, and came up with the following idea:

1. Have someone in the same LAN as the server take a "snapshot" of the directory using the CIFS share the server provides. This includes the hash, path and other info of every file.
2. The snapshot will be sent to me via email
3. I will take a similar snapshot of my local copy and compare the two. As a result I will have a list of new, deleted, modified, moved, and copied files.
4. I can live with manual download and changes to my local copy, but the "moved" and "copied" statuses as per point (3) above are especially important to me, so that I do not have to download large files whenever somebody rearranges the directory tree on the server.

Before I start developing a custom solution I did some research, but I seem not to be able to find a suitable tool. It would be perfect if git could take the above mentioned "snapshot" of a non-versioned folder.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

PS for completeness: the server as well as every involved client are Windows-based (XP or 7).

Comment: It is probably _much_ more secure (and much less work) to just use `rsync`... Is there _really_ no way to convince whoever gave this to be solved? The simplest "custom solution" I can think of is to rename `rsync` to `OurFunkyNIHSolution` and install that...

Comment: @vonbrand Haha, I will use that "trick" next time! Unfortunately this is not an option in this case. Thank you anyway.